Overlaying a div with an svg using CSS grid layout when div size is unknown ahead of time
I have a div:

it has width, but it is not known ahead of time
it might or might not have height set
when height is not set, it should expand vertically to match content.

I want to overlay that div with an SVG:

SVG has a square view box
SVG should take up exactly the size of the div.

I know this could be done using position: relative/absolute. I am trying to use CSS grid layout to achieve this, though.
Here's the code I have:


#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
}

#d1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

#overlay {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="d1" style="width: 20em;">
    <p>Some content here.</p>
    <p>Some content here.</p>
  </div>
  <svg id="overlay" viewBox="0 0 3 3" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="purple" opacity="0.5" />
    </svg>
</div>



https://jsfiddle.net/w2mucxvL/

The problem is: browsers seem to be ignoring preserveAspectRatio="none", which causes SVG to be square (instead of the size of #d1, which is not square). What am I missing?

Provided your SVG contains only shapes accepting relative units (e.g <rect>, <cirlcle>, <line> etc) you may as well just remove the viewBox and preserveAspectRatio attribute entirely. Any 100% width/height element will fill the entire area. In other words for fluid SVG layouts you don't need a viewBox.

You have to disable the size contribution of the SVG so that it doesn't affect the size of the grid but rather consider the grid size to be sized:


#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;
}

#d1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

#overlay {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  contain: size; /* disable size contribution */
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="d1" style="width: 20em;">
    <p>Some content here.</p>
    <p>Some content here.</p>
  </div>
  <svg id="overlay" viewBox="0 0 3 3" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="purple" opacity="0.5" />
    </svg>
</div>



Written differently:


#wrapper {
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;
}

#d1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

#overlay {
  grid-area: 1 / 1;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="d1" style="width: 20em;">
    <p>Some content here.</p>
    <p>Some content here.</p>
  </div>
  <svg id="overlay" viewBox="0 0 3 3" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="purple" opacity="0.5" />
    </svg>
</div>




Because with viewBox="0 0 3 3", the svg has its own default size of the aspect ratio of a square. So the grid is taking account of the dimensions of the SVG as well.
For an overlay, you could make the SVG position: absolute so its dimensions will be ignored by its parent #wrapper.
Together with setting position: relative to the #wrapper, the SVG will be covering only the size of #wrapper correctly.


#wrapper {
    display: grid;
    width: fit-content;
    height: fit-content;
    /* added */
    position: relative;
}

#d1 {
    grid-area: 1 / 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    border: 5px solid black;
}

#overlay {
    grid-area: 1 / 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* added */
    position: absolute;
}
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="d1" style="width: 20em;">
        <p>Some content here.</p>
        <p>Some content here.</p>
    </div>
    <svg id="overlay" viewBox="0 0 3 3" preserveAspectRatio="none">
        <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="purple" opacity="0.5" />
    </svg>
</div>




I was looking for a solution different from using position: absolute/relative, as stated in the question.

Ah, didn’t read through that, my bad.
